# How to read data off a dataset in JAX

Tags: python, jax

I am brand new to JAX. I have this code below, which has "features matrix" as an array, and "target vector" as an array. But I don't want the program to read off THESE data arrays. These arrays were there in the code already. I want to adapt the code so that it reads off the Boston house prices dataset, which I have imported. Could someone please tell me what alterations I need to make to this code so that I can make the linear regression work?

```
import jax.numpy as np
from jax import grad, jit

from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import sklearn.linear_model as sk

boston = load_boston()
X = np.array(boston.data)
y = np.array(boston.target)

def J(X, w, b, y):
    """Cost function for a linear regression. A forward pass of our model.

    Args:
        X: a features matrix.
        w: weights (a column vector).
        b: a bias.
        y: a target vector.

    Returns:
        scalar: a cost of this solution.    
    """
    y_hat = X.dot(w) + b # Predict values.
    return ((y_hat - y)**2).mean() # Return cost.

# A features matrix.
X = np.array([
                 [4., 7.],
                 [1., 8.],
                 [-5., -6.],
                 [3., -1.],
                 [0., 9.]
             ])

# A target column vector.
y = np.array([
                 [37.],
                 [24.],
                 [-34.], 
                 [16.],
                 [21.]
             ])

learning_rate = 0.01

w = np.zeros((2, 1))
b = 0.

%timeit grad(J, argnums=1)(X, w, b, y)

%timeit grad(J, argnums=2)(X, w, b, y)

for i in range(100):
    w -= learning_rate * grad(J, argnums=1)(X, w, b, y)
    b -= learning_rate * grad(J, argnums=2)(X, w, b, y)
    
    if i % 10 == 0:
        print(J(X, w, b, y))
```

Comment: You define `X` and `y` from the boston dataset, then re-define `X` and `y` further down. If you want to use the first `X` and `y` that you defined, then you should remove the statements that re-define those values.